# Sitecore 8.1 MVC add video

Tags: asp.net-mvc, sitecore, sitecore8.1

We are working with Sitecore 8.1 MVC Experience Editor and we try to add a video into the page. Right now we are trying with a Youtube video.

We have found some materials for sitecore 7 on John West [blog](http://www.sitecore.net/learn/blogs/technical-blogs/john-west-sitecore-blog/posts/2013/01/render-field-values-for-mvc-solutions-using-the-sitecore-aspnet-web-cms.aspx) from 2013 but nothing for Sitecore 8.1 and how should we implement the component to render the video.

The solutions we have found are all for webforms. There is no Video field and we don't know exactly how to integrate it with Experience editor.

Do you have some idea how this should be implemented?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can check this module: https://marketplace.sitecore.net/Modules/S/Sitecore_Youtube_Media_Connector.aspx?sc_lang=en

It's for Sitecore 7.2 but I suggest you to get source code and compile it with Sitecore 8.1 dlls. 
https://github.com/himadric/Youtube-for-Sitecore
For the Experience Editor I suggest you to use Edit Frames to edit video field.

All the code for edit frame in Mvc solution you can find at: 
https://gist.github.com/richardszalay/5088286